# Calculate Triangle area using tan

Tags: trigonometry

I have this question:

The triangle ABC is a right angle triangle at the C corner, and have angle x at A corner. We know that the side |AB|=8 and tanx=1/3. What is the AREA of the Triangle?

I've tried to use a mix of the trigometric identites +  sin2x+cos2x=1 to solve this, but I always end up with the wrong area. Any tips on how to calculate this kind of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area equals to $$\frac{1}{2}*AC*BC=\frac{1}{2}AB^2*\sin x* \cos x=32*\tan x*\cos^2 x=
32*\tan x* \frac{1}{\tan^2 x+1}=9.6$$

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your input. I used this formula for the other questions and It helped a lot, i understand how to calculate these kind of questions now. I have another similar question, may I ask it here, or I make new question? Thanks

Comment: you can wright it here, if it is similar to your first one

Comment: I posted a new post, did not see you write here. Please, could you check my new post if you have time?

Comment: Ок, I see another man answered you. God luck on this site